# Selenium/Python - Lag In Code?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I wrote some code to extract Insider Trading information from the Toronto Stock Exchange. Using Selenium, open up [this link](https://app.tmxmoney.com/research/insidertradesummaries?locale=EN) and then, using a list of stocks, one by one input each into the form, retrieve the data and put it into another list, then do the same for the next stock.

Here is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

stocks = ['RKN','MG','GTE','IMO','REI.UN','RY']
dt = []

url = 'https://app.tmxmoney.com/research/insidertradesummaries?locale=EN'

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

search = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//ul[@class="nav nav-pills"]/li[3]')
search.click()

stock_form = driver.find_element_by_name('text')

for stock in stocks:
    stock_form.clear()
    stock_form.send_keys(stock)
    stock_form.submit()
    data = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="insider-trades-symbol-search-container"]/div[@class="ng-binding"]')
    a = data.text.split('\n')
    if len(a) > 1:
        dt.append(a[-1].split())
    else:
        dt.append([])

driver.close()
```

If you run the code, you can see each stock being input into the form, the data will pop up and I attempt to retrieve it. However, when I get the text from "data", its as if its retrieved from what was visible on the page prior to submitting the form. I tried adding a wait to the code to no avail.

Comment: I am actually getting the `dt` list containing 6 items where the first one is an empty list, but all the rest are different lists starting from `['RKN', '1,008,600', '0', '1,038,394', '0', '5', '0', 'CDN']` and ending with `['REI.UN', '96,717', '0', '2,402,151', '0', '294', '0', 'CDN']`. Is this what you want it to return? If yes, I guess you do have a timing issue..

Comment: Yes, thanks. That’s what I mean. The first entry should be for RKN in the dt list. The last should be empty and that stock had no activity (I believe).

Comment: Solution: add time.sleep(1) between 'data' and 'a'. I guess there is, what I would call, a lag.

Comment: Hardcoding time delays like this is error-prone and fragile..see if you can have `WebDriverWait` with a specific condition applied instead..

Comment: I did attempt to use the implicit wait option in Selenium, but that did not seem to work. I guess I should try an explicit wait in time. What about them is error prone and fragile?

Answer (score 0):

added a time.sleep(1) and the code works as intended.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

stocks = ['RKN','MG','GTE','IMO','REI.UN','RY']
dt = []

url = 'https://app.tmxmoney.com/research/insidertradesummaries?locale=EN'

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

search = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//ul[@class="nav nav-pills"]/li[3]')
search.click()

stock_form = driver.find_element_by_name('text')

for stock in stocks:
    stock_form.clear()
    stock_form.send_keys(stock)
    stock_form.submit()
    data = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="insider-trades-symbol-search-container"]/div[@class="ng-binding"]')
    a = data.text.split('\n')
    **time.sleep(1)**
    if len(a) > 1:
        dt.append(a[-1].split())
    else:
        dt.append([])

driver.close()
```